# Как прослушивать изменения в mysql

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs

Как можно это сделать? Пишу аля чат на react + php, данные добавляются все окей, но обновления UI нет

Comment: Прослушивать - никак, нет такой буквы. Только поллингом (периодическим опросом таблиц на предмет изменения).

Comment: и как реализовать этот поллингом?

Comment: Введите в таблицы поле штампа времени обновления. Опрашивайте с нужной периодичностью таблицы на предмет вернуть записи, у которых значение в этом поле превышает максимальное значение на момент предыдущего опроса.

Comment: так это будет лишняя нагрузка ведь, если никто писать ничего не будет

Comment: мне нужно просто выводить последнюю запись если она появилась

Comment: Нагрузка будет. А вот насчёт того, что лишняя - это спорно...

Comment: Может быть попробовать websockets?
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/WebSockets

Answer (score 0):

Почитай про Server Sent Events https://learn.javascript.ru/server-sent-events